# Parallel tree traversal in C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, tree-traversal

I need to traverse a tree quickly, and I would like to do it in parallel. I'd rather use the parallel extensions than manually spin up a bunch of threads.

My current code looks something like this:

```
public void Traverse(Node root)
{
    var nodeQueue = new Queue<Node>();
    nodeQueue.Enqueue(root);
    while (nodeQueue.Count != 0)
    {
        var node = nodeQueue.Dequeue();
        if (node.Property == someValue) DoSomething(node);
        foreach (var node in node.Children)
        {
            nodeQueue.Enqueue(node);
        }
    }
}
```

I was really hoping that `Parallel.ForEach` had a `Parallel.While` analog. I came across Stephen Toub's article on [Implementing Parallel While with Parallel.ForEach](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/implementing-parallel-while-with-parallel-foreach/). If read it correctly this still won't work because I am mutating the queue I am trying to iterate.

Do I need to use a task factory and recursion (and is that risky?) ? or is there some simple solution I am overlooking?

@svick:

The tree has just over 250,000 nodes.
The maximum depth right now is 14 nodes deep including the root.

There are about 500 nodes off the root, and the balance after that has a fairly random distribution.
I'll get some better stats on the distribution soon.

@Enigmativity:

Yes, the tree is being modified, concurrently by many users, but I will usually have a shared read lock for the tree or sub tree, or allow for dirty reads.

Calls to `node.Children` can be considered atomic.

`DoSomething` is really one of several delegates, for some expensive operations I will probably gather a snapshot list of nodes and process them outside the traversal.

I realized that I should probably look at the general case (a sub-tree being traversed instead of the entire tree.) To that end I ran traverse on every node of the tree and looked at the total time.

I used a `Parallel.ForEach(nodes, Traverse)` for each traversal algorithm, where nodes contained all ~250k nodes. This simulated (sort of) a lot of users simultaneously requesting a lot of different nodes.

00256ms Breadth First Sequential

00323ms Breadth First Sequential with work       (i incremented a static counter as "work")

01495ms Kirks First answer

01143ms Svicks Second answer

00000ms Recursive Single Threaded didn't finish after 60s

00000ms Enigmativity's answer didn't finish after 60s

@Enigmativity, I think it's possible I might have messed up your algorithm somehow, because it seems like it should be much quicker.

The results surprised me to say the least.
I had to add some work to the breadth first sequential just to convince myself that the compiler wasn't magically optimizing away the traversals.

For the single traversal of the head, parallelizing the first level only had the best performance. But just barely, this number improved as I added more nodes to the second level (2000 instead of 500).

Comment: I'm not sure parallelizing this is a good idea.  It makes sense if you know exactly how many iterations you'll need at the very beginning.  Here, you won't necessarily know how many iterations will be needed until you visit the children.  A simple producer/consumer should be sufficient IMO.

Comment: @Jeff, why would parallelization only made sense if you knew the count of iterations exactly?

Comment: @Jason, what can you tell us about the shape of the tree? What is its maximum depth? Is it balanced? How wide many children each node has?

Comment: @svick: Well when you start traversing a tree, you have access to only one node, the root.  You won't know and cannot access the other nodes until you actually visit the node.  So it's weird to me to say that one would want to parallelize traversing a single node.  It's more natural for me to look at it as coming up with a list of nodes to visit.  When a node is visited, add the children to the list and continue until all found nodes in the list have been visited.  This is where the producer/consumer pattern makes sense to me where all threads are both producer and consumer.

Comment: @Jeff, obviously you can't parallelize traversing one node, but traversing the whole tree, makes perfect sense. And if you mean you'll have multiple producer/consumer threads, then that is a way of parallelizing the code.

Comment: @svick: Sorry, mixing things up here and wasn't as clear as I meant.  Jason was considering parallelizing using `Parallel.ForEach()` and which was what I was commenting on.  Yeah we can traverse the tree in parallel, just that using `Parallel.ForEach()` to do that didn't sound right.

Comment: Sorry, I think I might have been unclear. I don't plan on using Parallel.ForEach(), I mentioned that I wished that there was a similar Parallel.While(). Imagine my brief happiness at seeing Parallel.Do() ;_)

Comment: @Jason - Are you modifying the tree during your traversal?

Comment: @Jason - Is the traversal of the tree the expensive operation or is it the call to `DoSomething`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most direct way would be to create a `Task` for each child node and then wait for all of them:

```
public void Traverse(Node root)
{
    if (node.Property == someValue)
        DoSomething(node);

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var node in node.Children)
    {
        // tmp is necessary because of the way closures close over loop variables
        var tmp = node;
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Traverse(tmp)));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

`Task` is fairly light-weight, so creating lots of them works reasonably well. But they do have some overhead, so doing something more complicated like having a few tasks that share a queue is probably going to be faster. If that's the way you're going to go, don't forget that empty queue doesn't mean all work is done. Classes from the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace are going to come handy if you went this way.

**EDIT:** Because of the shape of the tree (the root has about 500 children), processing just the first level in parallel should give good performance:

```
public void Traverse(Node root, bool parallel = true)
{
    if (node.Property == someValue)
        DoSomething(node);

    if (parallel)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(node.Children, node =>
        {
            Traverse(node, false);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var node in node.Children)
        {
            Traverse(node, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and unfortunately it performed worse than the single threaded code from my question... It took about 20% more CPU time, and surprisingly, about 300% more clock time. I measured both in ANTs profiler, and did additional stopwatch testing just to make sure the profiler itself was not causing the slowdown.

Comment: On a separate note System.Collections.Concurrent has been very useful, I'm throwing in a bit of FSharpSet here and there too.

Answer (score 3):

I might be missing something, but I don't see the need for a `while` at all.  The `while` is just ensuring that you iterate over every node.

Instead just call your function recursively for each node in the tree.

```
public void Traverse(Node root)
{         
    if (root.Property = someValue) DoSomething(node);    
    Parallel.ForEach<Node>(root.Children, node => Traverse(node));
}
```

edit: of course the alternative, if you prefer to process horizontally rather than vertically and your expensive operation is DoSomething, is to do the `Traverse` first.

```
public IEnumerable<Node> Traverse(Node root)
{
    // return all the nodes on this level first, before recurring
    foreach (var node in root.Children)
    {
        if (node.Property == someValue)
            yield return node;
    }

    // next check children of each node
    foreach (var node in root.Children)
    {
        var children = Traverse(node);
        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            yield return child;
        }
    }
}

Parallel.ForEach<Node>(Traverse(n), n => DoSomething(n));
```

Comment: Looks simple, lots of nesting Parallel.Foreach. Note the use of a queue to walk the tree does it horizontally, recursion, vertically; this could change the logic (but in this case it looks like only if there are side-effects to DoSometing).

Comment: I think this addresses the 'problem' in a clean, simple way.

Comment: ... but I've added another solution for horizontal traversal, just for fun.

Answer (score 2):

Since the traversal of the tree is extremely fast, that calls to `Children` are atomic, and that it is the expensive nature of the `DoSomething` delegates that need to be executed in parallel, here's my take on the solution.

I started with the idea that I needed a function that takes a node as a parameter, creates a task that executes `DoSomething`, recursively calls itself to create tasks for all of the children nodes, and finally returns a Task that waits for all of the internal tasks to be completed.

Here it is:

```
Func<Node, Task> createTask = null;
createTask = n =>
{
    var nt = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        if (n.Property == someValue)
            DoSomething(n);
    });
    var nts = (new [] { nt, })
        .Concat(n.Children.Select(cn => createTask(cn)))
        .ToArray();

    return Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(nts, ts => { });
};
```

All that is required to call it and wait for the traversal to complete is:

```
createTask(root).Wait();
```

I tested this by creating a tree of nodes with 500 children off of the root with 14 levels, with 1 or 2 subsequent children per node. This gave me a total of 319,501 nodes.

I created a `DoSomething` method that performed some work - `for (var i = 0; i < 100000 ; i++) { };` - and then ran the above code and compared it to processing the same tree in series.

The parallel version took 5,151 ms. The sequential version 13,746 ms.

I also performed a test where I reduced the number of nodes to 3,196 and increased the processing time for `DoSomething` by 100x. The TPL very cleverly reverts to running sequentially if its tasks complete quickly so lengthening the processing time made the code run with more parallelism.

Now the parallel version took 3,203ms. The sequential version took 11,581ms. And, if I only called the `createTask(root)` function without waiting for it to complete it took just 126ms. This means that the tree is traversed very quickly, and it would then make sense to lock the tree during traversal and unlock it when processing is taking place.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you use the breadth first single threaded algorithm for comparison, or a recursive one?

Comment: @Jason - I used a recursive, breadth-first, single-threaded algorithm. Why did you think it was one or the other and not both?

Comment: In my tests, the single threaded recursive function was very slow. I didn't see the speed improvements you saw, so I was wondering what you were comparing your algorithm to.

Comment: @Jason - I tested my algorithms along with the other answers posted here. Once I got the balance right with `DoSomething` taking long enough that the TPL did execute it asynchronously I found that everyone's answersincluding mine, where about the same. A big tick for the folks that built the TPL - it really rocks for performance and flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have *p* processors maybe you do a **Parallel.For** over *root.Children* with *p* partitions. Each of these would do the traditional single-thread traverse over the subtrees, compare, and, rather than **DoSomething**, would enqueue a delegate to **DoSomething** to a concurrent queue. If the distribution is basically random and balanced and since traversal only does traversal/enqueue, that portion takes *1/p* th the time. Also, traversal would likely exhaust itself before all the *DoSomethings* would execute, so you could have *p* consumers (executors of **DoSomething**) giving you maximum parallel execution, assuming all these operations are independent.

With this naive partitioning across the number of root children with randomly distributed subtrees, traversal itself will be speedy. With your consumers roughly allocated per processor, you also get max parallel **DoSomething** action.

Answer (score 1):

People often overcomplicate problems like this by being using an imperative code style, which leads to doing all the complicated work inside of the recursive function. Presumably, traversing your nodes is very fast, and you're hoping to get value from parallelizing calls to DoSomething, right?

Here's a simple and generic method you can use to get every node from any tree-like structure:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetSelfAndDescendants<T>(T root, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getChildren)
{
    yield return root;
    foreach (var descendants in getChildren(root).SelectMany(child => GetSelfAndDescendants(child, getChildren)))
    {
        yield return descendants;
    }
}
```

With this in your tool belt, you can do something like this:

```
GetSelfAndDescendants(rootNode, n => n.Children)
    .Where(node => node.Property == someValue)
    .AsParallel()
    .ForAll(DoSomething);
```

This separates the problem of traversing the tree from the problem of processing its nodes, which means the recursive part of the process doesn't have to complicate the parallel part.

Also, since now there's only one entry point into the parallel library (the call to `AsParallel()` only happens once), you have a lot more control over how many tasks are executing concurrently. That's important because if you spin up ten thousand parallel threads they're all just going to be contending for resources and won't actually complete any faster. I suspect this is why the other answers had such poor performance: they're spinning up new threads at every level of recursion, so even if each `Parallel.ForEach` is limiting concurrency, there are dozens or hundreds of them getting invoked at the same time.

Using the approach I've detailed, you can either let .NET pick a sane default for you, or you can call `.WithDegreeOfParallelism(...)` to play with different numbers of concurrent tasks.

Based on [my test cases](http://share.linqpad.net/33gxxf.linq), with DoSomething just running through a non-optimized `for (var i = 0; i < 100000 ; i++) { }`, this takes about one tenth as long as a simple `foreach` across the same collection.

I should note that if DoSomething doesn't lend itself to parallelism (e.g. it locks on shared resources), you may still find that it's faster to process the items serially.

> DoSomething is really one of several delegates, for some expensive operations I will probably gather a snapshot list of nodes and process them outside the traversal.

This works well for that use case: just add a `.ToList()` in the appropriate spot to capture the nodes.

### Update

> > Presumably, traversing your nodes is very fast, and you're hoping to get value from parallelizing calls to DoSomething, right?
>
> No. In this case, it was the actual traversal that I was trying to optimize. This was for a system handling a lot of data near real time and we were trying to stay under 200ms for entire calls to the system not just the traversal.

In that case, it might be reasonable to follow svick's advice and just parallelize the top level of child nodes in your tree. If DoSomething() does practically nothing, then starting with a call to this method can boost your performance significantly:

```
public void Hybrid(Node root)
{
    if (root.Property == someValue) DoSomething(root);
    Parallel.ForEach(root.Children, Traverse);
}
```

[image: Benchmark results]

Benchmark: http://share.linqpad.net/gpc4pc.linq

Of course, that assumes that you can really benefit from multiple cores (i.e. your system isn't handling a bunch of other operations at the same time). If traversing your tree is really your performance bottleneck, and you find yourself traversing the tree often enough for it to matter, I'd consider whether your problem can be solved better with a different data structure and algorithm.

Comment: >Presumably, traversing your nodes is very fast, and you're hoping to get value from parallelizing calls to DoSomething, right?


No. In this case, it was the actual traversal that I was trying to optimize. This was for a system handling a lot of data near real time and we were trying to stay under 200ms for entire calls to the system not just the traversal.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two parallel versions of the `Traverse` method. The first is the simplest one. The `ParallelTraverse` invokes a synchronous delegate for the root node and its descendants (its children, its children's children etc). The iterator uses a [`Stack<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1) instead of a `Queue<T>`, for reasons of memory efficiency. The `Stack<T>` will contain at any moment only a handful of nodes. On the contrary a `Queue<T>` would store more than a half of the total number of nodes. Regarding the various ways that a tree can be traversed, you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830174/how-to-flatten-tree-via-linq) question.

```
/// <summary>
/// Invokes a delegate for a node and all its descendants in parallel.
/// </summary>
public static ParallelLoopResult ParallelTraverse<TNode>(
    TNode root,
    ParallelOptions parallelOptions,
    Action<TNode, ParallelLoopState> body,
    Func<TNode, IReadOnlyList<TNode>> childrenSelector)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(parallelOptions);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(body);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(childrenSelector);
    IEnumerable<TNode> Iterator()
    {
        Stack<TNode> stack = new();
        stack.Push(root);
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            TNode node = stack.Pop();
            yield return node;
            IReadOnlyList<TNode> children = childrenSelector(node);
            if (children is null) continue;
            for (int i = children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                stack.Push(children[i]);
        }
    }
    return Parallel.ForEach(Iterator(), parallelOptions, body);
}
```

Usage example:

```
ParallelOptions options = new() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount };
ParallelTraverse(root, options, (node, state) =>
{
    if (node.Property == someValue) DoSomething(node);
}, node => node.Children);
```

Only the `body` is parallelized. The `childrenSelector` is called sequentially (for one node at a time).

The second version has identical signature and features, and differs only in the behavior. The `ParallelTraverseHierarchical` ensures that the `body` of all nodes will not be invoked before the completion of the `body` of their parents. This can be important in case, for example, that the nodes must be saved in a database, and saving a node requires the autogenerated `ID` of its parent.

```
/// <summary>
/// Invokes a delegate for a node and all its descendants in parallel.
/// Children are invoked after the completion of their parent.
/// </summary>
public static ParallelLoopResult ParallelTraverseHierarchical<TNode>(
    TNode root,
    ParallelOptions parallelOptions,
    Action<TNode, ParallelLoopState> body,
    Func<TNode, IReadOnlyList<TNode>> childrenSelector)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(parallelOptions);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(body);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(childrenSelector);
    using BlockingCollection<TNode> stack = new(new ConcurrentStack<TNode>());
    stack.Add(root);
    int pendingCount = stack.Count;

    Partitioner<TNode> partitioner = Partitioner.Create(
        stack.GetConsumingEnumerable(), EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);

    return Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, parallelOptions, (node, state) =>
    {
        try
        {
            body(node, state);
            if (state.ShouldExitCurrentIteration) return;
            IReadOnlyList<TNode> children = childrenSelector(node);
            if (children is null) return;
            Interlocked.Add(ref pendingCount, children.Count);
            // Ideally the children should be added all at once as an atomic
            // operation, but although the ConcurrentStack does have an atomic
            // PushRange method, the BlockingCollection doesn't expose this feature.
            for (int i = children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                stack.Add(children[i]);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref pendingCount) == 0)
                stack.CompleteAdding();
        }
    });
}
```

This version parallelizes both the `body` and the `childrenSelector`. One of the two delegates is expected to be chunky. In case both are feather-weight (in the magnitude of microseconds), the overhead of passing every individual node through the `BlockingCollection<T>` might negate the benefits of parallelization. I have uploaded [here](https://gist.github.com/theodorzoulias/cb7616aa8f10656e81a72ccd7eb11d86) a more sophisticated implementation of the `ParallelTraverseHierarchical` method, based on a stack of stacks, that can traverse millions of nodes per second.

The scenario mentioned above, saving a tree in the database, requires that the `TNode` type has a mutable property for the database Id, and also that it has a reference to its parent node. This way each node will be able to retrieve the autogenerated `ID` of its parent. In case this requirement is not easy to meet, the above implementation could be enhanced by changing the type of the `body` parameter from `Action<TNode, ParallelLoopState>` to `Func<TNode, TArg, ParallelLoopState, TArg>`. The `TArg` would be a generic parameter that would pass information to the children about their parent. This information could be transferred through the blocking collection: `BlockingCollection<(TNode, TArg)>`. The `TArg` for the `root` node could be passed as an extra parameter in the method.

Comment: I like that your implementation avoids recursive functions, thereby also avoiding stack overflows for very tall trees.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using a List or Array instead of queue would help.  Also use another List/Array to populate the next nodes to visit.  You won't be processing list that until you finish the entire width first anyway.  Something like this:

```
List<Node> todoList = new List<Node>();
todoList.Add(node);
while (todoList.Count > 0)
{
    // we'll be adding next nodes to process to this list so it needs to be thread-safe
    // or just sync access to a non-threadsafe list
    // if you know approx how many nodes you expect, you can pre-size the list
    ThreadSafeList<Node> nextList = new ThreadSafeList<Node>();  

    //todoList is readonly/static so can cache Count in simple variable
    int maxIndex  =  todoList.Count-1;
    // process todoList in parallel
    Parallel.For(0, maxIndex, i =>
    {
        // if list reads are thread-safe then no need to sync, otherwise sync
        Node x = todoList[i];

        //process x;
        // e.g. do somehting, get childrenNodesToWorkOnNext, etc.

        // add any child nodes that need to be processed next
        // e.g. nextList.add(childrenNodesToWorkOnNext);
    });

   // done with parallel processing by here so use the next todo list
   todoList = nextList;
)
```