# Parallel BFS rush hour solver

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, breadth-first-search

So, for uni we have to do this assignment where we have to make a serial implementation of a rush hour solver parallel. The solver uses a Breadth First Search (BFS) implementation.

Here is a part of the default BFS implementation:

```
// Initialize empty queue
Queue<Tuple<byte[], Solution>> q = new Queue<Tuple<byte[], Solution>>();

// By default, the solution is "no solution"
foundSolution = new NoSolution();

// Place the starting position in the queue
q.Enqueue(Tuple.Create(vehicleStartPos, (Solution)new EmptySolution()));
AddNode(vehicleStartPos);

// Do BFS
while (q.Count > 0)
{
    Tuple<byte[], Solution> currentState = q.Dequeue();

    // Generate sucessors, and push them on to the queue if they haven't been seen before
    foreach (Tuple<byte[], Solution> next in Sucessors(currentState))
    {
        // Did we reach the goal?
        if (next.Item1[targetVehicle] == goal)
        {
            q.Clear();
            foundSolution = next.Item2;
            break;
        }

        // If we haven't seen this node before, add it to the Trie and Queue to be expanded
        if(!AddNode(next.Item1))
            q.Enqueue(next);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(foundSolution);
Console.ReadLine();
```

I managed to turn this into parallel like this:

```
ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<byte[], Solution>> q = new ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<byte[], Solution>>();

foundSolution = new NoSolution();

q.Enqueue(Tuple.Create(vehicleStartPos, (Solution)new EmptySolution()));
AddNode(vehicleStartPos);

while (q.Count > 0 && !solutionFound)
{
    Tuple<byte[], Solution> currentState;
    q.TryDequeue(out currentState);

    Parallel.ForEach(Sucessors(currentState), (next) =>
    {
        // Did we reach the goal?
        if (next.Item1[targetVehicle] == goal)
        {
            solutionFound = true;
            foundSolution = next.Item2;
            return;
        }

        // If we haven't seen this node before, add it to the Trie and Queue to be expanded
        if (!AddNode(next.Item1))
            q.Enqueue(next);
    });
}
```

As you can see, I tried to implement a parallel foreach loop with a `ConcurrentQueue`. I get the feeling like the concurrentQueue works well, but it locks automatically and thus costs too much time, making this parallel implementation way slower than the serial one.

I was thinking about having a wait-free or at least lock-free queue, so I can save that bit of time, but I am not sure how to implement such thing. Could you guys give some insight into whether this would be feasable and whether it would be faster than using a regular Queue ? Or maybe use a different concurrent data structure to better suit the situation. Not sure how well a ConcurrentBag and the like would fit in. Could you shed some light on this ?

Also, after having searched for parallel BFS implementations, I couldn't find any. What are some general tips and hints for people like me wanting to implement BFS in parallel ? What are some good alternatives for the queue, to make it thread-safe ?

EDIT1:
I managed to implement tasks like this:

```
int taskNumbers = Environment.ProcessorCount;
Task[] tasks = new Task[taskNumbers];

// Set up the cancellation token
ctSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

for (int i = 0; i < taskNumbers; i++)
    tasks[i] = new Task(() =>
    {
        try{    Traverse(); }
        catch{ }
    }, 
    ctSource.Token);

for (int i = 0; i < taskNumbers; i++)
    tasks[i].Start();

Task.WaitAll(tasks);

ctSource.Dispose();
```

They call a traverse method, which looks like this:

```
private static void Traverse()
{
    ctSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    while (q.Count > 0)
    {
        Tuple<byte[], Solution> currentState;

        if (q.TryDequeue(out currentState))
        {
            foreach (Tuple<byte[], Solution> next in Sucessors(currentState))
            {
                // Did we reach the goal?
                if (next.Item1[targetVehicle] == goal)
                {
                    ctSource.Cancel();
                    foundSolution = next.Item2;
                    return;
                }

                // If we haven't seen this node before, add it to the Trie and Queue to be expanded
                if (!AddNode(next.Item1))
                    q.Enqueue(next);
            }
        }

        if (ctSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            ctSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}
```

Yet, I am having trouble figuring out the condition for the while loop in the traverse method. The current condition allows for tasks to exit the loop too early. As far as I know, I dont have a complete list of all nodes available, so I cant compare the visited tree to the list of all nodes. Besides that, I don't have any other ideas of how I can keep tasks looping through the while loop until I have found an answer or until there are no more new nodes. Could you guys help me out ?

Thanks @Brian Malehorn for your help so far, I managed to get the performance of the parallel BFS version up to almost equal the performance of the serial version. All I need now is to make tasks stay in the while loop I think.

Comment: Please provide code inline. Make sure you have proper rights to the source to be posted under [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (which may not be the case for homework assignment). Also make sure your solution is of good quality and readable  so you classmates are not ashamed when turning in copy-pasted version.

Comment: @Alexei I have already torn apart this file and put some things in seperate .cs files myself. For the sake of ease I figured I could use the given rush hour solver (which was in one file by default). Besides that, I figured to not post it inline, since that would make a messy long post, but thanks for the tip ! I will definitely use it in future posts ! Regarding the proper rights, I am not sure if that is an issue.

Comment: Related: [Parallel tree traversal in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099703/parallel-tree-traversal-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't your queue, the problem is you're parallelizing the wrong thing. You're parallelizing *adding* the successors to the queue, when you should be parallelizing the `Sucessors()` call.

That is, `Sucessors()` should only be called from a worker thread, never in the "main" thread.

For example, suppose `Sucessors()` takes 1 second to run, and you're searching this tree:

```
                           o
                          / \
                         /   \
                        o     o
                       / \   / \
                      o   o o   o
```

The fastest you can search this tree is 3 seconds. How long will your code take?

Comment: I am not sure how long my code would take, probably more than 3 seconds. If I understand it correct, what you are trying to say is that I should make the entire while loop run on threads, instead of use a parallel.foreach ? if so, do you recommend to use  task or thread objects ? and how would you come up with an amount of tasks/threads and a distribution ? this question is the one of the only things which kept me from using tasks, and opting for the Parallel.foreach

Comment: Yes, you'll need to change to some sort of parallel while loop, so you'll want to use tasks. You should have the same number of workers as you have cores in your computer. Nothing terrible happens if you go too high, so a wild guess of 8 workers should be fine (most consumer computers have <= 8 cores).

Comment: What about the concurrentQueue ? I feel like I can get a speedup there, since I think it uses locks in its operations. Could you shed some light on possibly faster alternatives on that front ?

Comment: 99% of your speedup will come from doing the concurrency properly.There is such a thing as a lockless queue, but locking around an O(1) function like concurrentQueue does is more than fast enough for your use case.

Comment: What would I use as a condition for the while loop ?

Comment: Loop until you find a solution or the queue is empty (no solution).

Comment: We are looking into reliable ways of finding that out, making small progress. Thnx for your help so far !