# How to implement parallelism with a recursive method?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have a tree structure, for that I am using this class:

```
class Node
{
    long IdNode;
    List<Node> Childs;
    string path;
    Data data;
}
```

The path is the IdNode spearated by ".", so the path of a Node is "IdParent.IdNode" and so on. So to set the path of a node I need the path of the parent.

I have this method:

```
public setPath(Node paramParentNode)
{
    this.path = paramParentNode.Path + "." + this.IDNode;

    foreach(Node iteratorNode in this.Childs)
    {
        iteratorNode.setPath(this);
    }
}
```

This is a secuential version. But I was  thinking how to implement this in parallel, something like that:

```
public setPathMt(Node paramParentNode)
{
    this.path = paramParentNode.Path + "." + this.IDNode;

    Parallel.Foreach(this.Childs,
     (iteratorNode) =>
      {
          iteratorNode.SetPathMt(this);
      }
     );
}
```

But I don't know if this a correct way, because I don't know how to wait the recursive call of the method, I mean, how I know when the recursive methods are finished.

Which would it be the best way to implement the multithread recursive method of that?

Thanks.

Comment: And why parallelize such thing at all? Concatenating 2 strings with a dot should not take much time in sequential version?

Comment: Related: [Parallel tree traversal in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099703/parallel-tree-traversal-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method should be like

```
public SetPath(Node paramParentNode)
{
    paramParentNode.Path = paramParentNode.Path + "." + this.IDNode;

    foreach(Node iteratorNode in paramParentNode.Childs)
    {
        SetPath(iteratorNode);
    }
}
```

and Parallel method like this

```
public SetPathMt(Node paramParentNode)
{
    paramParentNode.Path = paramParentNode.Path + "." + this.IDNode;

    Parallel.Foreach(paramParentNode.Childs,
     new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 32 },
     (iteratorNode) =>
      {
          SetPathMt(iteratorNode);
      }
     );
}
```

You were not using the node passed in the method at all. When you use `this` it means the instance of that class, which would remain same in all recursive methods. The only thing changing would be the parameter passes in the method.

`new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 32 }` is to restrict the number of concurrent operations(threads) used by this Parallel operation to 32 (can be a number you want) or -1 (All available threads).

Comment: Where is parallelism here?

Comment: @Evk: that was coming up.

Comment: You might want to add in `new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 32 },` (or whatever's reasonable). But in fact I'm not even sure if this limit will apply to all simultaneous calls to Parallel.ForEach, or just each invocation, meaning if your tree is 1000 levels deep you could have a lot of threads running at once.

Comment: @DylanNicholson: Yes of course. This would restrict the number of parallel thread to be run. Thanks for pointing that out. Updated my answer.

Comment: This seems logically incorrect. First, `this.IDNode` is always the same, so the same string is appended to all paths (no recursive path building). Second, `paramParentNode` should be parent node, and you are passing child node there.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal As posted this code will not compile, easy enough to add `void` though. Nonetheless as @Evk commented it does not appear to do what the OP was requesting.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to run this operation in parallel. I think you'd need a very large tree to get any advantage. But either way the following code is a complete working example that builds the paths as you spec'd them:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary2 {

    [TestFixture]
    public class NodePathHandler {

        [Test]
        public void SetNodePathsTest() {
            var tree = new Node() {
                IdNode = 1,
                Childs = Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(nId1 => new Node() {
                    IdNode = 1 + nId1,
                    Childs = Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(nId2 => new Node() {
                        IdNode = nId1 + nId2,
                        Childs = Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(nId3 => new Node() {
                            IdNode = nId2 + nId3,
                            Childs = Enumerable.Empty<Node>().ToList()
                        }).ToList()
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList()
            };
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            SetNodePaths(tree);
            Console.WriteLine($"Time: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
        }

        public void SetNodePaths(Node node, string parentPath = null) {
            node.Path = parentPath == null ? node.IdNode.ToString() : $"{parentPath}.{node.IdNode}";            
            //Sequential
            //node.Childs.ForEach(n => SetNodePaths(n, node.Path));
            //Parallel
            Parallel.ForEach(node.Childs, n => SetNodePaths(n, node.Path));
            Console.WriteLine($"Node Id: {node.IdNode} Node Path: {node.Path}");
        }
    }

    public class Node {
        public long IdNode { get; set; }
        public List<Node> Childs { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public Data Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data { }
}
```

And the output for the small sample tree is:

```
Node Id: 2 Node Path: 1.2.2.2
Node Id: 3 Node Path: 1.2.2.3
Node Id: 2 Node Path: 1.2.2
Node Id: 3 Node Path: 1.2.3.3
Node Id: 2 Node Path: 1.3.3.2
Node Id: 3 Node Path: 1.3.4.3
Node Id: 3 Node Path: 1.3.3.3
Node Id: 3 Node Path: 1.3.3
Node Id: 4 Node Path: 1.2.3.4
Node Id: 4 Node Path: 1.3.4.4
Node Id: 4 Node Path: 1.3.4
Node Id: 3 Node Path: 1.2.3
Node Id: 3 Node Path: 1.3
Node Id: 2 Node Path: 1.2
Node Id: 1 Node Path: 1
Time: 4ms
```

Another option to note would be to take the `Sequential` example and add a call to `AsParallel().ForAll` instead of the `ForEach`. Usually that represents greater overhead than the `Parallel` class but if you're really concerned about performance then the variant is worth throwing in the mix.