# Multi-threaded tree traversal in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, locking, tree-traversal

I am trying to write a C# system that will multi-threaded traverse a tree structure. Another way to look at this is where the consumer of the `BlockingCollection` is also the producer.

The problem I am having is telling when everything is finished.
The test I really need is to see if all the threads are on the `TryTake`.
If they are then everything has finished, but I cannot find a way to test of this or wrap this with anything that would help achieve this.

The code below is a very simple example of this code as far as I have it, but there is a condition in which this code can fail. If the first thread just passed the `test.TryTake(out v,-1)` and has not yet executed the `s.Release();` and it just pulled the last item from the collection, and the second thread just performed the `if (s.CurrentCount == 0 && test.Count == 0)` this could return true, and incorrectly start finishing things up.

But then the first thread would continue on and try and add more to the collection.

If I could make the lines:

```
if (!test.TryTake(out v, -1))
     break;
s.Release();
```

atomic then I believe this code would work. (Which is obviously not possible.)

But I cannot figure out how to fix this flaw.

```
class Program
{
    private static BlockingCollection<int> test;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        test = new BlockingCollection<int>();

        WorkClass.s = new SemaphoreSlim(2);

        WorkClass w0 = new WorkClass("A");
        WorkClass w1 = new WorkClass("B");

        Thread t0 = new Thread(w0.WorkFunction);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(w1.WorkFunction);

        test.Add(10);

        t0.Start();
        t1.Start();

        t0.Join();
        t1.Join();

        Console.WriteLine("Done");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    class WorkClass
    {
        public static SemaphoreSlim s;

        private readonly string _name;

        public WorkClass(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
        }

        public void WorkFunction(object t)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int v;

                s.Wait();

                if (s.CurrentCount == 0 && test.Count == 0)
                    test.CompleteAdding();

                if (!test.TryTake(out v, -1))
                    break;
                s.Release();


                Console.WriteLine(_name + " =  " + v);
                Thread.Sleep(5);
                for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)
                    test.Add(i);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done " + _name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Another way to look at this is where the consumer of the BlockingCollection is also the producer.` That's actually one of the very, very rare cases where a ConcurrentBag could be more efficient

Comment: So.. what you need to know is when the last thread doing stuff has just finished processing the last node of the tree, yes?

Comment: Related: [Parallel tree traversal in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099703/parallel-tree-traversal-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 1):

This can be parallelized using task parallelism. Every node in the tree is considered to be a task which may spawn sub-tasks. See [Dynamic Task Parallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963551.aspx) for a more detailed description.

For a binary tree with 5 levels that writes each node to console and waits for 5 milliseconds as in your example, the ParallelWalk method would then look for example as follows:

```
class Program
{
    internal class TreeNode
    {

      internal TreeNode(int level)
      {
        Level = level;
      }

      internal int Level { get; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      ParallelWalk(new TreeNode(0));

      Console.Read();
    }

    static void ParallelWalk(TreeNode node)
    {
      if (node == null) return;

      Console.WriteLine(node.Level);
      Thread.Sleep(5);

      if(node.Level > 4) return;

      int nextLevel = node.Level + 1;
      var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                 () => ParallelWalk(new TreeNode(nextLevel)));
      var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                 () => ParallelWalk(new TreeNode(nextLevel)));

      Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
    }
}
```

The central lines are where the tasks t1 and t2 are spawned.

By this decomposition in tasks, the scheduling is done by the [Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) and you don't have to manage a shared set of nodes anymore.