# Parallel.ForEach and foreach returning different reference vars

Tags: c#, recursion, foreach, ref, parallel.foreach

(EDIT: If the title is confusing I'm all ears for a better one)

I'm currently working on a small project for class in C#, and I've come into something strange. The purpose of the project is to count all folders, files, and the size of files in a given directory, both in `foreach` and `Parallel.ForEach`.

Initially I was making it a recursive return function, but was having issues with the base case given that it had to account for all possible code paths with returns. I then switched to using ref params. Below I have current code for the methods.

```cs
/*
* Calculate total directories, count of files, and size of all files from
* a given path using a singular foreach. Update passed reference parameters.
*/
static void singRecurse(DirectoryInfo di, ref int countFolder, ref int countFile,
    ref long countByte)
{
    try{
        DirectoryInfo[] directories = di.GetDirectories();
        foreach(DirectoryInfo d in directories){
            countFolder += 1;
            foreach(FileInfo f in d.GetFiles()){
                countFile += 1;
                countByte += f.Length;
            }
            singRecurse(d, ref countFolder, ref countFile, ref countByte);
        }
    } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException){
        Console.WriteLine("You do not have access to this directory");
    }
}

/*
* Calculate total directories, count of files, and size of all files from
* a given path using a parallel foreach. Update passed reference parameters.
*/
static void parRecurse(DirectoryInfo di, ref int countFolder, ref int countFile,
    ref long countByte)
{
    int countFolderinLambda = countFolder;
    int countFileinLambda = countFile;
    long countByteinLambda = countByte;

    try{
        DirectoryInfo[] directories = di.GetDirectories();
        Parallel.ForEach(directories, d => {
            countFolderinLambda += 1;
            foreach(FileInfo f in d.GetFiles()){
                countFileinLambda += 1;
                countByteinLambda += f.Length;
            }
            parRecurse(d, ref countFolderinLambda, ref countFileinLambda,
                ref countByteinLambda);
        });
    } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException){
        Console.WriteLine("You do not have access to this directory");
    }

    countFolder = countFolderinLambda;
    countFile = countFileinLambda;
    countByte = countByteinLambda;
}
```

Current output from running both as separate processes results in:

```
Parallel calculated in 44ms
6 folders, 20 files, 250498 bytes
    
Single calculated in 11ms
8 folders, 25 files, 405153 bytes
```

Why is there such a discrepancy?

Comment: The order in which directories/files are counted varies between parallel and foreach. At some point you may hit the UnauthorizedExceptions, where your counting stops. Also it may be a good idea to use Interlocked.Increment for your counters in parallel.foreach to avoid racecondition

Comment: this is definitely something I need to take into account. That said, this directory is small and shouldn't have any of these issues (hence nothing written to console about unauthorized access)

Comment: as said in my edit, checkout  Interlocked.Increment

Comment: For what it's worth: I highly doubt you're going to get a performance boost by trying to parallelize this particular problem. The overhead of managing threads will probably be far greater than any threading advantages you'll get.

Comment: Related: [Parallel tree traversal in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099703/parallel-tree-traversal-in-c-sharp). @StriplingWarrior and myself have posted recent answers in that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive function is assigning a **relative total** to the **actual total**.

```
countFolder = countFolderinLambda;
countFile = countFileinLambda;
countByte = countByteinLambda;
```

Consider this function is running in parallel for multiple directories, and they're all **assigning** their own number to `countFile` without the knowing anything about other parallel directories.

For example,

```
w/ has 5 files
w/x/ has 3 files
w/y/ has 10 files
w/z/ has 7 files
```

- The parallel branch for w/x/ is **setting** the total to 8 files
- The parallel branch for w/y/ is **setting** the total to 15 files
- The parallel branch for w/z/ is **setting** the total to 12 files

Each parallel is undoing the work of the previous.

Instead, make the recursive function count the relative files and then **add** to the totals instead of reassigning to them. See below - note that I've renamed your variables to `relativeX` and `totalX` for added clarity.

```
void parRecurse(DirectoryInfo di, ref int totalFolders, ref int totalFiles, ref long totalBytes)
{
    int relativeFolders = 0;
    int relativeFiles = 0;
    long relativeBytes = 0;

    try
    {
        DirectoryInfo[] directories = di.GetDirectories();
        Parallel.ForEach(directories, d =>
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref relativeFolders);
            foreach (FileInfo f in d.GetFiles())
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref relativeFiles);
                Interlocked.Add(ref relativeBytes, f.Length);
            }
            parRecurse(d, ref relativeFolders, ref relativeFiles, ref relativeBytes);
        });
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You do not have access to this directory");
    }

    Interlocked.Add(ref totalFolders, relativeFolders);
    Interlocked.Add(ref totalFiles, relativeFiles);
    Interlocked.Add(ref totalBytes, relativeBytes);
}
```

---

As an aside, after writing various recursive functions I tend to gravitate towards creating a container class for the data instead of passing refs. Classes are passed by reference, which simplifies things. Something like this:

```
public class FileSystemCountContext
{
    private int _directories = 0;
    private int _files = 0;
    private long _bytes = 0;

    public int Directories => _directories;
    public int Files => _files;
    public long Bytes => _bytes;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Directories} directories, {Files} files, {Bytes} bytes";
    }

    public void IncrementDirectories()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _directories);
    }

    public void IncrementFiles()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _files);
    }

    public void IncrementBytes(long amount)
    {
        Interlocked.Add(ref _bytes, amount);
    }
}


FileSystemCountContext CountFileSystem(DirectoryInfo directory, bool parallel = false, FileSystemCountContext? context = null)
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        context = new();
    }

    foreach (FileInfo fi in directory.GetFiles())
    {
        context.IncrementFiles();
        context.IncrementBytes(fi.Length);
    }

    if (parallel)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(directory.GetDirectories(), di =>
        {
            context.IncrementDirectories();
            CountFileSystem(di, parallel, context);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo di in directory.GetDirectories())
        {
            context.IncrementDirectories();
            CountFileSystem(di, parallel, context);
        }
    }

    return context;
}
```

Comment: This implementation is subject to race conditions. Every `+=` is translated into a LOAD, an ADD, and a STORE. If two threads each LOAD the same value, they'll be adding and storing the same value too.

Comment: Thank you - good point, although race conditions is not the root cause of the issue, it makes for a flawed answer. I've updated it to use `Interlocked`